# what is the benefit of .net core healthcheck for a web api project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In .net core, I can write a health check function like this example and implement a custom class `SqlConnectionHealthCheck`. But I can also just create a real endpoint /Health and implement the same check there. Can someone explain the benefit of using AddHealthChecks other than creating an endpoint called /Health? Or they are pretty much the same thing?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    // Registers required services for health checks
    services.AddHealthChecks()
        // Add a health check for a SQL Server database
        .AddCheck(
            "OrderingDB-check",
            new SqlConnectionHealthCheck(Configuration["ConnectionString"]),
            HealthStatus.Unhealthy,
            new string[] { "orderingdb" });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the `AddHealthChecks` is a middleware and is (partially) *independent* from other parts of the application.
Obviously a middleware is inserted in the chain of the other middleware, but the endpoints are created *inside* the healthcheck implementation and doesn't depend on other parts.

I think that the healthchecks should be **external** in order to verify an application context outside the application itself, but it's only another view of the problem.

This example, from Ms docs, is really exhaustive:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/health-checks/samples/5.x/HealthChecksSample/DbContextHealthStartup.cs

Just my 5 cents.

Comment: My example comes from the MS HealthChecksSample, but my problem is that I can't see the benefit with their examples. Our current health check just calls a controller's exposed method with a predefined request, for me, that seems be a better or as good as what MS can offer.

Comment: @daxu it's all about how you structure your codebase. If you just want your Controller endpoints to do business use cases then AddHealthChecks is good because you are separating your infrastructure from your business use cases.

Comment: separating infrastructure  from business use is good, but even if a database is on, it doesn't mean the specific data loading routine or your business case is working (e.g. in a database context, it could be blocked, could be parameter sniffed).